# Реально ли поставить хук на дополнительные клавиши ноута?

Tags: hook

Есть ноут, Dell v131. Пишу для его кнопок (дополнительных) софт свой. Точнее хочу написать. Как повесить на них хук? Глобальный сработает? Если да, подкиньте полезную статью.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно можно. Нужно только узнать коды этих клавиш (вот в [этой](http://www.opennet.ru/base/X/media_keys.txt.html) статье, например, показано как - но она для никсов), а остальное - то же самое, что и с обычными клавишами.

Answer (score 3):

Для Asus'ов есть подобная программка, называется AsusNBKeys. Для нее есть исходники. [Тут](http://asusfans.ru/659-multimediynye-goryachie-klavishi-fn-v-audio-video-prilozheniyah.html) описание и ссылки на файлы.